# Broadcast intent vs multicast listener implementation on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, listener, broadcast

I want to enable for several objects to subscribe to an event at the same time.

Currently I see two approaches: to send broadcast intents, or to implement multicast listeners (a manager class containing an array of the subscribed listeners, and with subscribing and unsubscribing functionality) such as the built-in events in C#.

Which is the best practice on Android? Or is there any other approach worth considering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html), which is a lightweight solution for sending broadcast intents, and it is a part of Android support library v4.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a decent solution:)

Answer (score 1):

> Which is the best practice on Android?

If you are trying to do this between apps, use broadcasts.

If you are trying to do this within one app, use [an existing event bus implementation](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/32), such as Otto or greenrobot's EventBus, rather than reinventing that wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribing each object to a broadcast receiver may not be a good idea because the execution sequence is unknown. At the top level you can have a single broadcast receiver which will receive the intent and have a logic to notify all the listeners inside it.